# Postgres - Setting Azure Active Directory Admin to a group fails (but it works to set it to a User)

Tags: postgresql, azure

I am trying to set the AAD admin for a Postgres Server.
If I use a browser I can succesfully set the admin to a user, but not to a group. The log shows the following error

```
"statusMessage": "{\"status\":\"Failed\",\"error\":{\"code\":\"ResourceOperationFailure\",\"message\":\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"InternalServerError\",\"message\":\"An unexpected error occured while processing the request. Tracking ID: 'd5c4e07c-403b-431f-b863-gdgsdgs\"}]}}",
```

If I try to set it using the AZ CLI [az postgres server ad-admin create ...] I also get an error:

```
The 'parameters.properties' segment in the url is invalid.
```

Is there any workaround to set the AD Admin to an AD group for Postgres?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

@Ion Filip,

You could get this error if Instance Agent may not have the proper schema selected or somehow `public` schema from **search_path** is removed from your PostGre server. Please reset this parameter to its default value and try again.

In order to reset the parameter you need to -

1. Go to Azure portal. Navigate to your postgresql database.
2. Click on server parameters under settings. Look for the parameter **Search_path**
3. Click the three dots on the right and select "Reset to default".

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The search_path already contains the default value